# Working "in" or "at" workgroup?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english

Which one is the correct preposition to be used with workgroup word?

I am interesting in Working `in`or `at` your workgroup?

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+workgroup%2C+at+a+workgroup&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20workgroup%3B%2Cc0) indicates 'in' and that 'at' has no hits at all.

Comment: @NigelJ, I did not know about this Ngram, interesting. Could you answer it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/385483?redirectedFrom=workgroup#eid) gives one definition of a workgroup as :

> A group of employees within a workforce who regularly or habitually work together.

The OED then gives the usage as :

> 2003   M. Albert Parecon (2004) v. 92   Given a workplace's overall agenda, how the people **in a work group** organize themselves affects almost exclusively themselves.

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+workgroup%2C+at+a+workgroup&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20workgroup%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'in' is exclusively used as the preposition, there being no usage at all with 'at'.